# traitCollectionDidChange never called on UIView subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ios-darkmode, uitraitcollection

I have a `UIViewController` that is presented modally by another `UIViewController`. This `UIViewController` has a `UITableView` with a custom `UIView` set for it's `tableFooterView`.

So the issue I am having is: some colors are not displayed properly when switching the device's system appearance.
As I have read, `cgColor` does not adapt automatically to appearance changes:

> The color object in this property does not adapt automatically to
>   Dark Mode changes. If you use it to set the color of interface
>   elements, you must update that color yourself when the
>   userInterfaceStyle trait of the current trait collection changes. For
>   information on how to apply color information reliably, see Supporting
>   Dark Mode in Your Interface.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621954-cgcolor

So to tackle this I am overriding the `traitCollectionDidChange` inside the `UIView` that uses `cgColor` like this:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        updateView()
    }
```

In the `updateView` method, I simply update the `cgColor` properties of some sub layers, but this method never get called. I tried overriding this method in the `superview` of the `UIView` which has the same issue. It only gets called on the `UIViewController` level which is not useful because the `tableFooterView` is not set yet at that point in time.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: I would double-check your `updateView()` func... maybe put a `print("trait change")` statement in your `traitCollectionDidChange` function. This is working fine for me:   https://gist.github.com/DonMag/220cb07468ca8699be056a1f6d5719b7

Comment: I am pretty sure it's not being called, testing it with breakpoint, unless there is a chance that it's not stopping at the breakpoint even though it's executed.

Comment: Hmm... I updated that gist with a complete example. `PresentTestViewController` has a button that presents `TraitTestViewController`, which has a tableView with an instance of `TraitView` as its `.tableFooterView`. All via code - just set a view controller to  `PresentTestViewController` -- https://gist.github.com/DonMag/220cb07468ca8699be056a1f6d5719b7

Comment: This is interesting, I put your code in a new project and yes it works as expected. I am gonna look deeper into my code to see if anything else causes this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use UIDynamicColor from Assets, you can use it like this:

```
let newCgColor = someColor.resolvedColor(with: traitCollection).cgColor
```

For example:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    imageView?.layer.borderColor = Self.borderColor?.resolvedColor(with: traitCollection).cgColor
}
```

If it not about problem, you can delete it :)